# Get The Latest Successful Run Of A Pipeline If Branch Exists

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am migrating pipelines from TeamCity to Azure DevOps.  TeamCity allows for the creation of dependencies between builds that Azure DevOps doesn't.  My developers have a repo for database changes (multiple apps use this one database) and another for their application.

I need the application build/release pipeline to check to see whether there is a matching branch in the database repo and, if so, to get the latest successful build number for that branch.  If there is no matching branch, I will need the latest successful build on the main branch.

Once I know the build number I'll know which artifacts to grab and should be good to go.

I'm reaching out to the community to see if anyone has dealt with a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/).

- You can query for the existence of a branch using the [Git / Refs endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs)
- You can query for builds using the [Pipelines / Runs endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs)

You can call these endpoints from a pipeline, for example in a [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops).

You will need to add an authorisation header, based on an access token; if your pipeline's service account has all the right permissions, then you can simply use the pre-defined variable [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken); alternatively you can use a token from a different account, if you have generated it in advance and made it available to the pipeline.